# Word for "correct" that means "wrong" when halves are reversed

Tags: word-order, split

I have two identical electrical plugs which fit side-by-side.  It is important to get them the right way around as they will both fit in either socket.

I would like to write something on each of the two plugs to remind myself which way they plug in.

I could write `COR` on one and `RECT` on the second, so that when plugged in side-by-side they will read `CORRECT`.  When plugged in the wrong way around they will say `RECTCOR` which is obviously a mistake, so this is one possibility.

However I am wondering whether there is something better - two groups of letters that will mean correct/good/safe when placed next to each other in one order, but when the order is swapped the meaning will change to become incorrect/bad/dangerous instead.

(As a side note, the plugs and sockets can change orientation, so "left" and "right" don't work as holding the thing upside down means left and right become opposite.  There's also no room to write anything on the sockets, only on the plugs.)

Comment: How 'bout `hell` `o` and `o` `hell`? :D

Comment: This is off topic to the English Language Usage and not exactly what you are after but you could colour each socket and corresponding plug with different colours. For example the left plug and its socket can be coloured red and the other plug and socket could be coloured black.  That way it will not matter about orientation.  The correct socket will be matched with the correct plug

Comment: Not trying to push this away but I wonder if the puzzles stack exchange that might be helpful

Comment: Right way: ON. Wrong way: NO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question expertise in English will help answer. It's a puzzle, a rebus.

Comment: @DanBron: Fair point - can the question be migrated to Stack Exchange puzzles?  I didn't realise that site existed!

Answer (score 2):

“O” and “K”.  In the right order, they spell “OK”;
in the wrong order, they spell “KO”, which stands for “knock-out”.